# The easiest and most time efficent way to connect to the internet regardless of the cost

Tags: sensors, wifi, ethernet, servo, arduino-yun

I am working on my graduation Project. I want to use the cayenne (mydevices) platform to control my Arduino. Mainly I want to be able to control a servo Motor through the Cayenne app and I want to use a gyro sensor that would also control the servo using the app after obtaining the readings from the sensor. The Options are:
1- Yun arduino 
2- Arduino Ethernet
3- Arduino uno (which I currently have) + Arduino Ethernet shield or arduino wifi shield

Cayenne (mydevices) APP supports all of the above Options

What is the easiest to implement? I have short time period and working on the mechanical design for the Project in the same time.

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Option 2 and 3 are kind of the same, as the Arduino Ethernet has the same components as the Ethernet shield. The ethernetShieldV2 has a slightly newer chip on it, but I don't expect that much difference. The Yun might be easier, but the problem is that not a lot of people have used it, so there aren't a lot of tutorial online. So I'd probably go with  option 2 or 3. Unless you need HTTPS for the Cayenne API.

Comment: Guess there are a few more requirements such as bandwidth, message/protocol frequency, motor control speed, etc. Also available libraries and support.

Comment: What about the ESP8266 or a raspberry pi

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino Uno and Arduino Ethernet are very simple to program, to connect it to the Internet.

I never used the Yun Arduino, but it seems a little bit harder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with Arduino (instead of SBC), I suggest you use Arduino Yun.

The Linux side of the Yun will provide very much greater scope for web programming compared to Arduino+Ethernet shield. There also a bridge library to communicate with the Yun.